# What is the difference between a Page Builder and a Framework?

Tags: extensions, template-framework

I assume that a page builder is a kind of extension intended to build pages in terms of appearance and style.

On the other side, a template framework is a tool that allows us to modify template, which for me is very similar to the purpose of a page builder.

I am obviously missing something; what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template framework is a single home structure, and Page Builder is like a room inside. Each room can look different, but they still will be inside that home.

**Template framework:** 
it's a Layout Manager for module positions and to maintain Header, logo, color, fonts.

**Page builder:** 
Page Builder is a component - it means that operates only in the component area, like any other component. It has its own add-ons like: Tab, Accordion, Pricing Table, Team, Testimonial etc.  which you can place on the Page Layout.

My suggestion is Install Helix Ultimate quickstart pack. You can test both Helix Ultimate Framework and SP Page Builder. It's totally free. Follow their documentation it's too easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

#### Page Builder:

This allows you to build pages and each one can be different. For example, page specific modules, permissions, styling, and so on.
Page builders focus more on the **structure** and **content** of the page.

#### Template Framework:

The template is the overall design of your site so it's more generic and will normally apply any changes you make globally. These frameworks however do vary and some may allow page specific changes.
Due to the fact they're aimed more at your global site, they'll also include other sets of tools for compiling, compression, colour changes, etc.
Template frameworks focus on the **structure** and **styling** of your site.

Comment: If I understand well, my template framework will, for exemple, let me chose the color of my block of text, while the Page builder will allow me to construct a page with some block of text (of the same color). When starting the building of a website, should I start to focus on the Template Framework and then to the page builder (from general to specific ?).

Comment: Yes, start with the template and then the page builder. Or at least build a single page with the page builder first